# An internal server error occurred xampp Yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, xampp

Всем привет.При подключение сайта через xampp возникает ошибка  An internal server error occurred проект громадный и папки web нету есть папка frontend в котором находится index.php 
когда меняю код в нем

```
 defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
```

на

```
 defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
```

[image]

вот db.php

```
return [
    'db' => [
        'class' => yii\db\Connection::class,
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysanatorium;',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'fm4Nrfnd3',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'fv_',
        // Duration of schema cache.
        'schemaCacheDuration' => 3600,
        // Name of the cache component used to store schema information
        'schemaCache' => 'cache',
        'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    ],
    'coredb' => [
        'class' => yii\db\Connection::class,
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysanatorium;',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'fm4Nrfnd3',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'fv_',
        // Duration of schema cache.
        'schemaCacheDuration' => 3600,
        // Name of the cache component used to store schema information
        'schemaCache' => 'cache',
        'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    ],
];
```

показывает вот такую ошибку.Прошу не кидать помидоры я новичок в Yii и в PHP.Очень хотелось решить проблему так как уже неделью не могу установить сайт на локальный хост.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема было в том что только надо было удалить строку password и все

```
return [
    'db' => [
        'class' => yii\db\Connection::class,
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysanatorium;',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'fv_',
        // Duration of schema cache.
        'schemaCacheDuration' => 3600,
        // Name of the cache component used to store schema information
        'schemaCache' => 'cache',
        'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    ],
    'coredb' => [
        'class' => yii\db\Connection::class,
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysanatorium;',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => 'fv_',
        // Duration of schema cache.
        'schemaCacheDuration' => 3600,
        // Name of the cache component used to store schema information
        'schemaCache' => 'cache',
        'enableSchemaCache' => true,
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте параметры подключения к БД в конфиге. Сейчас ругается на то, что не может пользователь root подключиться к базе.

Создайте базу, взяв ее название из конфига в mysql. Файл sql - это дамп, нужно его импортировать в созданную базу, например через phpmyadmin.

Comment: окей шас по чекаю

Comment: я добавил db.php суда проверьте sql файл находится в папке mysql я подключил его через терминал.

Comment: А базы созданы в mysql? Файл sql - это дамп, нужно его импортировать в созданную базу, например через phpmyadmin